# cURL to AJAX - Parse.com Push

Tags: ajax, cordova, curl, parse-platform, phonegap-pushplugin

Hello I am using the Parse SDK with a Phonegap application and I am trying to implement push  notifications. I already have a plugin that gets me the device token and installation id. All I need now is to send that data to Parse.

Does anyone know how to use curl in javascript or convert this curl statement to ajax?

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 1234" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 1234" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
     "deviceType": "ios",
     "deviceToken": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
    "channels": [
      ""
    ]
  }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/installations
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you could to the following

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/installations",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
                  "X-Parse-Application-Id: 1234"
                  "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 1234"
                  "Content-Type: application/json"
        },
        data: {
            "deviceType": "ios",
            "deviceToken": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
            "channels": [""]
        },
        success: function(response){ /*whatever you want 
                                   to do with the response data*/
        }
    })
```